# Introducing new statements in java syntax

Tags: java, syntax

Is there a through which we can add new statement to java syntax like if i write the line

```
add(6)(5)(4)(3)
```

i get the answer 18

Comment: No, not in Java.

Comment: Nothing says you can't define a function to do something like that, however: `add(6, 5, 4, 3)`. But you still need to follow the basic syntactical rules of the language.

Comment: any other language like java script etc. if yes can you tell me how?

Comment: Are you going to choose a language based on that? That seems unreasonable.

Comment: For the 1000: can it be done with Java8 lambdas?

Comment: @UsmanTariq you can wait for java 9, 10 and so on...!!!

Comment: [SML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_ML_of_New_Jersey)

Comment: @RichardJPLeGuen It can be done in Scala

Answer (score 0):

what's wrong with using add(6,5,4,3)
with something like

```
public class Numbers {
    public int add(int... numbers) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int number : numbers) {
            sum += number;
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach that is similar in Java, would be to use [variable arguments](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html),

```
public static int add(int... args) {
    int r = 0;
    for (int i : args) {
        r += i;
    }
    return r;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = add(6, 5, 4, 3);
    int j = 6 + 5 + 4 + 3;
    System.out.printf("i = %d, j = %d\n", i, j);
}
```

If you wanted to use [JavaScript in Java](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rhino), I suppose you could.

Answer (score 0):

Write your own compiler.  In conjunction with the other answers, you will be able to write statements like you want to, and in under 10 million such uses it will pay for itself.